# How to prove forall n:nat, ~n<n in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq

I've been confused for hours and I cannot figure out how to prove

```
forall n:nat, ~n<n
```

in Coq. I really need your help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This lemma is in the standard library:

```
Require Import Arith.
Lemma not_lt_refl : forall n:nat, ~n<n.
Print Hint.
```

Amongst the results is `lt_irrefl`. A more direct way of realizing that is

```
info auto with arith.
```

which proves the goal and shows how:

```
intro n; simple apply lt_irrefl.
```

Since you know where to find a proof, I'll just give a hint on how to do it from first principles (which I suppose is the point of your homework).

First, you need to prove a negation. This pretty much means you push `n<n` as a hypothesis and prove that you can deduce a contradiction. Then, to reason on `n<n`, expand it to its definition.

```
intros h H.
red in H.   (* or `unfold lt in H` *)
```

Now you need to prove that `S n <= n` cannot happen. To do this from first principles, you have two choices at that point: you can try to induct on `n`, or you can try to induct on `<=`. The `<=` predicate is defined by induction, and often in these cases you need to induct on it — that is, to reason by induction on the proof of your hypothesis. Here, though, you'll ultimately need to reason on `n`, to show that `n` cannot be an m<sup>th</sup> successor of `S n`, and you can start inducting on `n` straight away.

After `induction n`, you need to prove the base case: you have the hypothesis `1 <= 0`, and you need to prove that this is impossible (the goal is `False`). Usually, to break down an inductive hypothesis into cases, you use the `induction` tactic or one of its variants. This tactic constructs a fairly complex dependent case analysis on the hypothesis. One way to see what's going on is to call `simple inversion`, which leaves you with two subgoals: either the proof of the hypothesis `1 <= 0` uses the `le_n` constructor, which requires that `1 = 0`, or that proof uses the `le_S` constructor, which requires that `S m = 0`. In both cases, the requirement is clearly contradictory with the definition of `S`, so the tactic `discriminate` proves the subgoal. Instead of `simple inversion H`, you can use `inversion H`, which in this particular case directly proves the goal (the impossible hypothesis case is very common, and it's baked into the full-fledged `inversion` tactic).

Now, we turn to the induction case, where we quickly come to the point where we would like to prove `S n <= n` from `S (S n) <= S n`. I recommend that you state this as a separate lemma (to be proved first), which can be generalized: `forall n m, S n <= S m -> n <= m`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Require Import Arith.
auto with arith.
```

Comment: It works. But I wonder if you could provide a proof without Arith. I really appreciate it.